# Fastest way to copy into an array random elements from another array C++

Tags: c++, c, sorting, fill

The title almost tells everything,but I will exemplify this: suppose that you have an array a of chars, and another array b also of chars. Is there a better way to put in a only the char located at prime positions in b? Suppose that we have an array with prime positions.
For now my naive code looks like this.

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
 a[i] = b[j + prime[i]];
```

Here prime[i] stores the prime positions of b and b is much larger than a,j is an arbitrary position in b(there will not be an out of bound problem because j+prime[i] does not exceed border of b).

Comment: Random or not? Choose

Comment: `prime` is not very random.

Comment: Are you asking for something faster than the loop you provided, or are there other parts of your program you are not showing that you want us to figure out how to make faster somehow?

Comment: There are some other parts that I haven't shown. I need to make a hashing function on parts of an array, a part consists of all the characters on prime positions and the other part consists of the remaining characters (not prime positions). Is there an efficient way to do this? I have tried to determine first the prime/not prime positions, then to copy the characters into prime/not prime array and only after this I apply the hashing function on each array.

Comment: How large is `n`? (At large values it may be advantageous to make a skip list (that encodes primes and double primes -- the only triple prime is 3,5,7)

Comment: n is very large 2 billion -10 billion . Can you be more specific about skip list?

Comment: A skip list would simply transfer the sequence of 3 5 7 11 13 17 to 2,2,2,4,2,4 etc. The benefit would be a) more compact storage of primes  and b) immediate application to copy with memcpy(dst, src, N); This method would possibly be useful at the range, where average N > 50 (perhaps). Also one could encode the double primes somehow and use a dedicated routine to copy N chars, skip 1 and copy 1 more. Anyway one should pursuit for bulk copying instead of one char at a time. The skip list can also be computed from a bitmask produced by a sieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do this when you read (or copy) values into the array, using a prime function that tells you if a number is prime or not.

A way I sketched quickly is to generate prime numbers until they reach your array capacity and simply  iterate through them and copy the desired elements from your **a** array. I can think of several ways of optimizing this, such as having a "preprocess" function that generates prime numbers in your program so you can reuse the list.

The prime number list will get cached and it will take a lot less time to be accessed(it s unlikely that you have an extremely huge prime number list)

Answer (score 0):

What is better? One way is: If the prime[] locations are known at compile time, then we could add a prefetch to get the cache lines in ahead of time.

This is making the memory access time better.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at this from an algorithmic perspective.

You want to perform a hash function on each of the entries in array A. Assuming that you know nothing about the state of the items in array A, then that places the lower bound of run time for the algorithm at O(n), linear time. You must iterate through every member because you don't have any more information that could assist you in "skipping" some elements or optimizing the process.

That said, the challenge then becomes keeping the algorithm down at O(n). The code you demonstrate does do this, assuming you then follow up with copying the non-prime numbers in the same manner. So for the copying step, no there is not a way to make this any faster from an algorithm point of view. That doesn't mean that how you perform the hashing step won't affect the speed, though.

Comment: the hashing is something like this: `for(i = 0; i < length; i++) hi = (hi<<1) + y[j + prime[i]]; ` Where length is <= n and j + prime[i] does not exceed n.